# Creating and Sharing pdf to Gmail app in Android 11

Tags: java, android, storage

So I am trying to create a pdf in my app and send that pdf as attachment to gmail app. All was good before android 11 scoped storage restrictions.

This are the files I am using :
provider_paths.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external"
        path="." />
    <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <cache-path
        name="cache"
        path="." />
    <external-cache-path
        name="external_cache"
        path="." />
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
 <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

This is the file that I am trying to add as attachment :

```
File filelocation = new File(context.getCacheDir() +"/", "Some#" + printBean.getId() + ".pdf");
```

Using the below to access Uri :

```
 Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getPackageName()+".fileprovider",filelocation);
```

but when I am passing the Uri with the intent for opening gmail

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{new UserPreference(context).getUser().getEmail()});
if (path != null) emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Mail PDF");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new UserPreference(context).getUser().getEmail());


emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, printBean);
   context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, context.getString(R.string.send_email)));
```

it gives me error "couldn't attach file".

Need Help.
Edit : Getting this exception in log :

```
ComposeActivity:Error adding attachment
    ggx: FileNotFoundException when openAssetFileDescriptor.
        at ggy.a(PG:6)
        at ggy.a(PG:45)
        at dod.a(PG:146)
        at dnk.run(PG:2)
        at dod.a(PG:184)
        at dod.a(PG:153)
        at dod.a(PG:452)
        at dkb.a(Unknown Source:3)
        at aezj.a(Unknown Source:5)
        at agzq.a(PG:2)
        at agzs.run(PG:9)
        at ahcg.run(Unknown Source:7)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
        at aexk.run(PG:2)
        at adjn.run(Unknown Source:3)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: "when I am passing the Uri with the intent for opening gmail" -- could you update your [mcve] to show this code?

Comment: `filelocation.exists()` could be added to your code before launching intent.

Comment: @blackapps its already there I have not added it here.

Comment: You could set a mime type too.

Comment: already using setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));.

Answer (score 0):

Well FiltUtils might be returning null. You can get the file like

```
val file = File(context.getCacheDir(), FILE_NAME) and afterwards pass
 FileProvider.getUriForFile(requireContext(),YOUR_PROVIDER_PACKAGE ,file)
```

File provider will give you the uri then you can pass that inside intent of sharing file

Comment: Already doing that. And its not returning null. I am getting the Uri but when passing to the intent it gives me error.

Comment: please show the logcat of the error here. Put try catch around the intent and print stack trace and let me know the stack trace so we could figure it out.

Comment: there is no exception in my app. Its just that the other apps cant access my files.  I have edited the question with the exception I am getting in logcat

Comment: I tried with outlook app and getting more detailed exception in logcat : 

java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider androidx.core.content.FileProvider from ProcessRecord{2ce4d39 5445:com.microsoft.office.outlook/u0a154} (pid=5445, uid=10154) that is not exported from UID 10155

Hope this helps

Comment: Make sure two things  , Point Number 1 : You have read and write permission , ask for run time permission for sdk above 21  Point number 2 : If you have that permission then first check that whether you have the file in that directory or not you can check if by val file = File ( YOUR_DIRECTORY , FILE_NAME)  file.exist( )